# Intuition behind general multiplication rule of probability theory

Tags: probability

I want to check if my understanding of conditional probability is correct so far.
[image: Example of my understanding]

Please have a look at the image and comment on whether it is accurate.

Comment: It is correct assuming that you are rolling a fair six-sided die.  Another way of seeing it is simply of the possible equiprobable results $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ only the result $2$ satisfies both conditions simultaneously.  This second approach is what would be done in the "using the venn diagram," but drawing the diagram is a great deal of effort to go through for such a small example.

Comment: If you have the time, I think you should take the time to convert your image to text. It's better for searching, editing and reading on non-conventional devices. Thanks.